# Find the sum of the convergent series involving a difference of cosines.

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence

$$\sum_{n=3}^\infty \cos\left(\frac{\pi}{n}\right) - \cos\left(\frac{\pi}{n+1}\right)$$

Trying to find a way to simplify this convergent series to $-1/2$. I've tried using the $\cos(A) - \cos(B)$ identity to simplify things. This is from a first year course so it shouldn't require anything too complicated. Most likely I'm forgetting something. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is a telecosping series. Try to sum two consecutive terms of the series and see if you can spot something.

Comment: Thanks! I'll give that a shot and let you know what I find :)

Comment: My hint is don't make numeric calculatons -- the symbols will take care of themselves.

Answer (score 0):

For $N\ge 3$,
$$\sum_{n=1}^N\left(\cos \left(\frac{\pi}n\right)-\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{n+1}\right)\right)=\cos\left(\frac{\pi}3\right)-\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{N+1}\right)$$
So, the series is telescopic. Now take the limit when $N\to \infty$.